# Error: Cannot find symbol (java)

Tags: java, string, methods, input

error: cannot find symbol (Line 23 of main class)
myRapidRefund.setDestination(destination);

symbol: method setDestination(String)
location: variable myRapidRefund of type RapidRefund

I've searched and couldn't find a solution. I presume the problem is in the get/set method but i cant figure it out it's been a while since I've used java. Any help is much appreciated thanks! Here's the code:

Main App class:

```
/*
 *@author k.Donohoe
 *4th Nov 2013
 *RapidRefundApp.java
 */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 public class RapidRefundApp{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         //declare variables
         String location, destination;
         int cash;
         double fare;

         //declare & Create objects
         RapidRefund myRapidRefund = new RapidRefund();

         //input
         location = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your current location");
         myRapidRefund.setLocation(location);

         destination = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your destination");
         myRapidRefund.setDestination(destination);

         cash = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How much change do you have?"));
         myRapidRefund.setCash(cash);

         //process
         myRapidRefund.compute();

         //output
         fare = myRapidRefund.getFare();
         if(fare==-1){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, you have entered an invalid day, please try again");
         }
         else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The cost of the ticket is "+fare);
         }
     }
 }
```

Instantiable Class:

```
/*
 *@author K.Donohoe
 *4th Nov 2013
 *RapidRefund.java
 */

 public class RapidRefund{
     //declare data members
     private String location, destination;
     private int cash;
     private double fare;

     //constructor
     public RapidRefund(){
         location = " ";
         destination = " ";
         cash = 0;
         fare = 0.0;
     }

     //set method(s)
     public void setLocation(String location){
         this.location = location;
     }

     public void setDesination(String destination){
         this.destination = destination;
     }

     public void setCash(int cash){
         this.cash = cash;
     }

     //compute method
     public void compute(){
         if(location.equals("IFSC")||location.equals("Stephens Green")||location.equals("O'Connell Street")||location.equals("Dublin Castle")){
            if(destination.equals("Powerscourt")){
                fare = 2.95;
            }
            else if(destination.equals("Ikea")){
                fare = 2.40;
            }
            else if(destination.equals("Phoenix Park")){
                fare = 2.15;
            }
            else if(destination.equals("Howth")){
                fare = 2.95;
            }
            else{
                fare= -1;
            }
         }
         else{
            fare = -1;
         }
     }

     //get method(s)
     public double getFare(){
         return fare;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction to your question. 1+ up-vote on the question and on Makoto's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a misspell of `destination`.

```
myRapidRefund.setDestination(destination);
```

does not match the signature in `RapidRefund`:

```
public void setDesination(String destination)
```

Remember:  Java doesn't care about spelling, as long as you're consistent!